# target=_blank attribute is not working in Literal string

Tags: c#, asp.net

the target attribute is not working in C# literal string, please give me the alternate way. below is the html attached

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    byte[] bytes =  (byte[])rdr["stock_pic"];
    string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;
    carName=rdr["carName"].ToString();
    Literal1.Text = Literal1.Text + "<tr><td>" + carName + "</td><td><a href="+Image1.ImageUrl+" target='_blank'>View</a></td></tr>";
}


   <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Stock No</th>
                        <th>Stock picture</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="100px" Width="100px" runat="server" />
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around the image url.

```
Literal1.Text = Literal1.Text + "<tr><td>" + carName + "</td><td><a href='"+Image1.ImageUrl+"' target='_blank'>View</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: still target attribute is not working , but when i right click on mouse and click on 'open link in a new tab' its displaying me image on new tab.  but target is not working yet

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes around "image1.imageurl".

Comment: still target attribute is not working , but when i right click on mouse and click on 'open link in a new tab' its displaying me image on new tab.  but target is not working yet

Comment: You probably has something wrong in the lonk. Copy the result html and put it into question.

Comment: please check the html sir